# Smooth function on a manifold not dependent on coordinate chart

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm having trouble with the proof of the following remark from page 59 of Tu's book on Manifolds. **The part I'm worried about is where he gets that $\phi\circ \psi^{-1}$ is $C^\infty$. Is he allowed to make that assumption?** I thought we could only say this if the two charts were $C^\infty$-compatible.

[image]

Other relevant definitions from his book:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth manifold is a $C^{\infty}$ manifold by definition and the transition functions of a $C^{\infty}$ manifold are supposed to be $C^{\infty}$ by definition.

Comment: He defines a smooth/$C^\infty$ manifold as being one with a maximal atlas. Does it follow from the presence of a maximal atlas that all of the transition functions are $C^\infty$ compatible? I guess this is probably a corollary.

Comment: Not from the maximal atlas. Generally, $M$ is a $C^k$ manifold if and only if there exists an atlas $(U_i,\phi_i)$ such that $\phi_i\circ {\phi_j}^{-1}$ is a differentiable map of class $C^k$, in particular, if $k=+\infty$, $M$ is a smooth manifold.

Comment: Okay. I added in pictures of his definitions to my question.

Comment: Pairwise $C^{\infty}$-compatible atlas means that $\phi_{\alpha}\circ {\phi_{\beta}}^{-1}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ map.

Comment: Okay. What I was worried about was what if $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are not compatible with the maximal $C^\infty$ atlas? I mean all I know is that the charts in the atlas are pairwise $C^\infty$ compatible, but might they not be compatible with other charts on $M$?

Comment: By definition a chart is compatible with all the charts

Comment: The relevant discussion is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660188/97129 .