# Smoothness of a function is independent from the chart

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I would like to revamp an old question ([Smooth function on a manifold not dependent on coordinate chart](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667997/smooth-function-on-a-manifold-not-dependent-on-coordinate-chart)) as I did not understand the reply.

In Loring Tu's book "An Introduction to Manifolds" I read (remark 6.2)

> Remark 6.2 The definition of the smoothness of a function $f$ at a point [of a manifold $M$] is independent of the chart $(U, \phi)$, for if $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is $C^\infty$ at $\phi(p)$ and $(V, \phi)$ is another chart about $p$ in $M$, then on $\psi(U \cap V)$,
>   $$f \circ \psi^{-1}=(f \circ \phi^{-1})\circ(\phi \circ \psi^{-1})$$
>   which is $C^\infty$ at $\psi(p)$.

My questions are:

- In order to have $(\phi \circ \psi^{-1})$ a $C^\infty$ function, don't we need to have $U$ and $V$ compatible with each other? Actually definition 5.5 of compatible charts relies on the smoothness of $(\phi \circ \psi^{-1})$ and $(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})$.
- So, in remark 6.2 shouldn't we add that $V$ is another chart **compatible** with U?
- Also, is a sense, isn't the smoothness of $f$ depending on our choice of maximal atlas (i.e. two charts belonging to two different atlases may not be compatible with each other)?

Thanks!

p.s. not sure if it is good practice to revamp a question in this way but I added more focused questions (I hope) and I don't have anough reputation yet to comment on a question which I haven't posted.

Comment: I don't understand. the definition of a (smooth) manifold asks for an atlas, but not necessarily all charts in p are contained in the same atlas

Comment: as far as I understand a maximal atlas in not contained in a larger atlas but this does not imply the existence of a unique maximal atlas. take for instance the two charts of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $x$ and $x^{3}$. They are two homeomorphisms of the full real line seen as a manifold that create two different coordinate sets, and can be seen as two atlases, but they cannot belong to the same maximal atlas as they are not compatible in 0. infact here the identity function fails to be smooth in 0 using the second atlas. no? where am I wrong?

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide

Comment: @justin FYI did you guys clarify further?

Comment: I mean... you're completely correct that the smoothness of $f$ *does* depend on your choice of smooth atlas. It's not a property of the manifold structure of $M$, as can be seen in even the most basic example of $M=\mathbb{R}$ with global chart $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$.

Comment: thanks a lot. so in my first two points should I consider $U$ and $V$ belonging to the same maximal atlas and f smooth if there is *at least* one maximal atlas for which it is smooth?

Comment: I think the safe way to phrase it just: Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, i.e. topological manifolds with distinguished smooth atlases (you can assume that they're maximal I guess), and let $f: M\to N$ be a map. Then, we define $f$ to be smooth if for every $x\in M$, there exist charts $(U,\phi)$ in $M$ and $(V,\psi)$ in $N$ such that $x\in U,$ $f(U)\subseteq V$ and $\psi \circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: Then, you have a lemma stating that the above definition is equivalent to the definition: a continuous $f:M\to N$ is smooth if for every chart $(V,\psi)$ in $N$ and and every chart $(U,\phi)$ in $f^{-1}(V)$, we have that $\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: i understand how the lemma implies the First definition but the contrary seems to hold to me only if i pick U and V from the original atlases... comments?

Comment: If $f$ satisfies the second definition, then it satisfies the first one. That's immediate. If $f$ satisfies the first definition, then note first of all that it must be continuous and then you apply the argument you're alluding to, i.e. that the conclusion that $f$ is smooth does not depend on the chosen charts (so long as we remain within our fixed smooth atlases).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107484/discussion-between-l4telearner-and-woolierthanthou).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotation from the end of section 5.3 (p. 53):

> From now on, a “manifold” will mean a $C^\infty$-manifold. We use the terms “smooth”
> and $C^\infty$ interchangeably. [...] By a *chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$* in a manifold $M$, we will mean a chart in the differentiable structure of $M$ such that $p  \in U$.

This means that the charts occurring in Definition 6.1 and Remark 6.2 are tacitly assumed to belong to the fixed differentiable structure which determines $M$ as a *smooth manifold*. In particular, the charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are automatically compatible.

A topological manifold $M$ may have different differentiable structures. See [In smooth atlases, are the identity homeomorphisms "supersets" for all other homeomorphisms on the smooth structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2923293) for simple examples. This shows that a map $f : M  \to \mathbb R$ defined on the topological space $M$ will not be smooth in an absolute sense, but only smooth with respect to the given smooth structure on $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Here's one additional question. It is written that "This means that the charts occurring in Definition 6.1 and Remark 6.2 are tacitly assumed to belong to the fixed differentiable structure...". What does the word 'fixed' mean in this case? To me it still makes sense if I omit the word 'fixed'. What am I missing here?

Comment: @rainman You are missing nothing. I just wanted to emphasize that the differentiable structure is a *constituent part* of the smooth manifold $M$. Therefore you can of course omit "fixed".